# Encrypt in Java and Dycrypt in JavaScript using Crypto JS not working

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptojs

I am newbee in both Java and JS and trying to Encrypt Password in java, which should be decrypted by my existing JS code.  (Do not want to change my JS !)

I think it has something to do with KEY and IV, which I am totally unaware about.

** JAVA PROGRAM **

```
public class Helper {

public Cipher dcipher, ecipher;

// Responsible for setting, initializing this object's encrypter and
// decrypter Chipher instances
public Helper(String passPhrase) {

    // 8-bytes Salt
    byte[] salt = {(byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03};

    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;

    try {
        // Generate a temporary key. In practice, you would save this key
        // Encrypting with DES Using a Pass Phrase
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);            

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeySpecException");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
    }
}

// Encrpt Password
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public String encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
        System.out.println("\n UTF8 : " + utf8);
        // Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        System.out.println("\n enc: " + enc);
        // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Helper encrypter = new Helper("");

        System.out.print("Enter a password : ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(password);
        System.out.println("encrypted String:" + encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

}

Above program should Encrypt key - which will be decrypted by following JS :

```
var encryptedpassword=this.bodyParams.password;

        var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedpassword.toString(), accKey);
        var newpassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

WHERE accKey = "*Nqnzu3RhCJ1h8ql5fdKOaKUAbsuURze**********_

Comment: 9/10 times these crypto issues are caused by JS's unicode strings and the other guys non-unicode strings...

Comment: Can you suggest what to do. I am new with both things so need little help here.

Comment: I would like to suggest that you simply don't decrypt a password but instead encrypt the incoming password utilizing the same key (or salt) and compare the two encryptions. Leave the password to be a super duper secret with the person that provided it. :D

Comment: On a side note, DES with MD5 is not very strong encryption. Upgrade to AES if you can.

Comment: Thank you suggestions @DevilsHnd ... but frankly speaking I am not even half way there with my knowledge which you are talking about. PLEASE , Can anyone help with Encryption code - which supports posted decryption code, PLEASE ?  So going through I will understand the code and how it works.

Comment: Thank you suggestions @didiz. Can you help me with code of encryption you are talking about.

Comment: If this is for passwords, you are going about it the wrong way.  I know you want help with the code you have, and thats fine, but if you want to do this properly so that it is **actually secure**, you should instead look into using TLS for communication and bcrypt for password hashing.

Comment: @LukePark : Sure I will go through TLS and bcrypt concepts for better understanding. Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you encrypt with DES and decrypt with AES.

Also you are generating a key from passphrase on your Java code, but using it directly on your JavaScript code.

You use salt on the Java side, but do not appear to incorporate the salt in the message. Having the salt+passphrase you can recover the key and iv.

You will need to look around for a another set of examples that use AES on both ends, that generate the key in the same way, and uses the same padding.

Something along the lines of this:

```
// Generate a temporary key. In practice, you would save this key
// Encrypting with AES Using a Pass Phrase
 KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 100, 128);
 SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
 SecretKey aesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(aesKey.getEncoded());
ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivParameterSpec);
```

You also need to consider TLS for communication as someone just mentioned in the comments, as it is fairly difficult to secure symmetric encryption keys/passphrases on the JS side.